# When is it safe to manipulate screen controls through code in iOS/Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a question regarding iOS (or perhaps more accurately Objective-C) and properties. I have a UIView with a UISegmentedControl, by default it has 3 segments. I have a message which accepts a parameter and based on this parameter I may want to remove one of the segments. In UIView A I do this:

```
MyViewController *myview = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" nib:nil] autorelease];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myview animate:YES];
[myview showItem:item];
```

In UIView B this happens in showItem:

```
-(void) showItem:(Item*)item{
    if (item.removeSegment){
        [segmentControl removeSegmentAtIndex:0 animate:NO];
    }
}
```

I have noticed that the segment only gets removed when I call showItem after I have pushed it on the navigation controller. When I swap those two line, so I first call showItem and then push the view, the UISegmentedControl still has three segments instead of two.

This just feels wrong, it seems like bad practice that my code will break if someone doesn't call two messages in the right order. Is there a better way to do this? I've been looking at some sort of a property lifecyle that I can use, I am very familiar with this from ActionScript 3, but I have been unable to find anything on the subject.

(as an aside: in AS3 I would make a property, in the setter I don't manipulate any screen controls but call InvalideProperties. My overriden methode CommitProperties will be called once the entire object and child controls have been created. In CommitProperties I check if my property value has changed and this is where I would remove the segment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way of doing something like this is to create an `Item *item` property in `MyViewController` and set that when `myview` is created.  So, your code becomes:

```
MyViewController *myview = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" nib:nil] autorelease];
myview.item = item;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myview animate:YES];
```

`MyViewController` would then use that property in its `viewWillAppear:` method to configure its own segment control.

Comment: But then the code breaks if someone would first push the view and then assign the property. Right?

Comment: No, because the property will still have been set when viewWillAppear is called. You shouldn't let external objects modify the views owned by a view controller - you should set state from the outside, and let the vc manage it's views based on state.

Comment: See [here](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/passing-data-between-view-controllers/) for Ole Begemann's excellent explanation of this.

Comment: @PhillipMills, my "no" was for Lorn, not you, if that wasn't obvious - I agree with your answer!

Comment: If you're worried about the timing of the property setting, the surest way would then be to create an `initWithItem:(Item *)item;` method and have that as the designated initializer for your class.  It would set its own property from the parameter and other code would be as I described (i.e. `viewWillAppear:`).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are falling prey to is myview->segmentControl doesn't exist until myview.view is referenced because of the lazy load of the view.

```
-(void) showItem:(Item*)item{
    [self view]; // NO OP TO FORCE LOAD!!
    if (item.removeSegment){
        [segmentControl removeSegmentAtIndex:0 animate:NO];
    }
}
```

Should work for you. Hope this helps!

Comment: Also try running it on the main thread, using dispatch / NSThread.

Comment: Not a great idea, though it does work. See http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/passing-data-between-view-controllers/ for a good read on this sort of pattern.

Comment: @jrturton yeah, I tend to use `+controllerWith…` myself, but I wanted to answer the specific question of how he can keep his pattern without the order dependency.